# How I can pass my event handler as $$restProps to child component

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

I have an **input component** like this:

```
<script lang="ts"></script>

<div class="wrap-input">
  <input
    class='input'
    type="text"
    {...$$restProps}
  />
</div>

<style lang="scss">
  // some styles
</style>
```

I used **input component** on the **parent**:

```
<script lang="ts">

  // function event handler
  const onKeyUp = (event) => {
    console.log(event)
  }
</script>

<main>
  <Input
    on:keyup={onKeyUp} // How I can send this event to input component as $$restProps
    className="input-todo"
    placeholder="What needs to be done ?"
  />
</main>

<style lang="scss">
  // some styles
</style>
```

Answer (score 5):

Based on the [event-forwarding](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/event-forwarding) tutorial,
`on:keyup` event directive without a value means 'forward all keyup events', so you can change your `Input` component to:

```
<div class="wrap-input">
  <input
    class='input'
    type="text"
    on:keyup
    {...$$restProps}
  />
</div>
```

[Example](https://svelte.dev/repl/91b85925bbfd4b758c0a37d779f7588d?version=3.44.2)

Comment: Yeah, this solution can help me! But I think it's good if have any way to send even-handler as $restProps, waiting for new features from Svelte.